# SignalR on SharePoint Farm Solution

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to create a SharePoint webpart using SignalR. At first I tried solution on MVC web site. And I moved files on SharePoint to get solution but it didn't happen. After that I research on the web again and agreed to develop it on SharePoint Hosted app. It worked! When I try to use it in SharePoint page as an App Part it has been in an iframe and it was not the thing what I want.

Returned to the beginning.

Checked all steps at that blog

http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/using-signalr-2-2-in-a-sharepoint-2013-farm-solution

and still no solution and getting error on ULS :

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Owin, Version=1.0.0.0,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f0ebd12fd5e55cc5' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>    at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build()

In my web config there is no 1.0.0.0 version Owin

Can anyone help?

Comment: You probably need to add the assemblies to your Package. Although I'm not sure why you would run SignalR in SharePoint when the app approach should work great (Provider-hosted, not SharePoint hosted), also, SignalR works well with CORS so you could run in instance anywhere really

Comment: In SharePoint apps I already launched my example. I need it in visual webpart.

Comment: What I'm trying to get at is; why is an iframe (used in App Part) a problem? You can have access to all the SharePoint data from within the iframe, CRUD on behalf of the user.

Comment: SharePoint App is good but is there any way to show SP.ModalDialog in whole page using App Part on SharePoint Page? If I try to use it for example it shows only its own iframe zone

Comment: You could instead show the app inside a dialog (iframe to the app). Not sure what the best approach is, but I did a simple test by calling `OpenPopUpPage` with the iframe src for an app part, and it worked

Comment: I solved my problem with adding all dll references which are dependent. But i need that app as a visual web part. No need to use Popup or Modal directly

Comment: Did you have to add all the assemblies to your package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with adding all dll references which are dependent. Owin, Newtonsoft.JSON, Microsoft.ASPNET.SignalR.* like that... It works now